# "Creation point" of automatic variable

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

```
void foo()  
{  
    //some code

    MyClass m();

    //some more code
}
```

Does the C++ standard ensure that the constructor of class `MyClass` will be called *after* `//some code` has run, or is it unspecified behavior?

Comment: I meant a declaration which calls a real constructor,
Myclass m(1,2, true);
keeping the mistake because it's a good point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The technical answer to this question is that the compiler will guarantee that the constructor isn't run at all, because the line

```
MyClass m();
```

is **not** a variable declaration.  Instead, it's a prototype for a function called `m` that takes no arguments and returns a `MyClass`.  To make this into an object, you need to drop the parens:

```
MyClass m;
```

Because this is such a source of confusion, in C++11 there is a new syntax you can use for initializing automatic objects.  Instead of using parentheses, use curly braces, like this:

```
MyClass m{};
```

This tells the compiler to use the nullary constructor for `MyClass` as intended, since there's no way to interpret the above as a function prototype.

If you make this change, the compiler will guarantee that `m`'s constructor is executed after the first piece of code and before the second piece of code.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

First of all `MyClass m();` doesn't create any object, you probably meant `MyClass m;`. Yes, it is guaranteed that the object is created only after `//some code` is ran.

Comment: I disagree with this. Can you quote the standard?

Comment: What part do you disagree with?  The function prototype part, or the ordering of the execution?

Comment: @templatetypedef the ordering part. In some cases the constructor doesn't even get called.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: The compiler is free to optimize creation of the object if it is not being used at all or it deems optimization is possible.However, if the need for creation of object exists then the order of execution of OP's code is fixed.The object will only be created *after* `//some code` is executed and *before* `//some more code` gets executed.

Comment: @Als "Does the C++ standard ensure that the constructor of class MyClass will be called after //some code has run, or is it unspecified behavior?". The answer is no. If you put some printf statements before and after `MyClass m;`, `MyClass::MyClass()` will still not be called.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: The Q here is not about the fact that compiler can optimize out the constructor call, it is about the order in which statements will execute, If the constructor *has to be* called it will only be after the said codes and no other way.

Comment: @Als I'm not going to make assumptions about what the question was intended to be.

Comment: @Als regardless, I edited my answer even with the constructor not optimized out.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: And yet your argument and answer assumes that the Q asks something it doesn't explicitly state.

Comment: @Als "Does the C++ standard ensure that the constructor of class MyClass will be called[...]". I don't know how to be any more clearer. Is the constructor **guaranteed to be called**?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: I don't see the referred quotation anywhere in OP's Q, OP's Q **clearly** states *Does the C++ standard ensure that the **constructor of `class MyClass` will be called after //some code has run, or is it unspecified behavior?***

Comment: @Als want to continue this in chat?

Answer (score 1):

There is no object being created here.

```
MyClass m();
```

Declares a function by the name `m` which takes no arguments and returns a object of type `MyClass`.

```
MyClass m
```

would create a object named `m` of the type `MyClass` and yes it is guaranteed that constructor for `m` will be called only when the that line of code is executed.

Answer (score 0):

`MyClass m();`  --> No object is being created here. Its just a declaration of function which takes no parameters but returns MyClass object.

If you need to create an object just write `MyClass m;` or `MyClass *m = new MyClass();`
Yes, constructor of MyClass is called after some code.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you meant to declare a variable, as has been remarked already:

```
void foo() {
  // {before}
  MyClass m;
  // {after}
}
```

Then *semantically*, the constructor is executed after *{before}* and before *{after}*.

Whether this holds during execution is covered by the as-if rule. That is, in order to allow optimizations, the Standard only offer guarantees about *observable* effects: whatever the execution model chosen, the observable effects should be as-if the code had been executed without any optimization.

Observable effects notably include:

- modification of `volatile` variables
- system calls (including memory operations)

By default, a function whose definition is unknown is supposed to have observable effects.

The notable exception is the *Copy Elision* optimization, which the Standard allows in a number of cases even though the copy constructor might have observable effects.

Concretely, it means that given:

```
int before();
int after();

void foo() {
  int n = 5;
  int const a = before();
  n += a;

  MyClass m;

  int const c = after();
  n += c;

  std::cout << n << "\n";
}
```

The Standard guarantees the following ordering:

- `before();`
- `MyClass m;`
- `after();`
- `std::cout << n << "\n";`

What is not guaranteed, however, is how `n` is computed. All that is known is that at the moment of printing it, it will be equal to `5 + a + c`, but whether the computation is delayed to just before printing or performed eagerly each time a new element is available is of no concern to you: it does not change the observable behavior.

Therefore, the two following versions of `foo` are equivalent:

```
void foo_eager() {
  int n = 5;
  n += before();
  MyClass m;
  n += after();
  std::cout << n << "\n";
}

void foo_lazy() {
  int const a = before();
  MyClass m;
  int const c = after();
  std::cout << (5 + a + c) << "\n";
}
```